# python xlwt: how to have header vrow repeat when printing

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm writing sheets in **xlwt** with a header row and a few hundred data rows.

I'd like the header row to print at the top of every printed page, when I print from Excel.

Can I effect this setting from xlwt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a way to manipulate print settings with xlwt.

Unfortunately [it doesn't appear possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt) to create a template excel file with the print settings and write the data to it.

If you're on windows, your best bet will probably be to use the pywin32 COM interface - create a template excel file that has your print settings, and write the data to it.  I haven't used this (I'm on a mac), but supposedly it works the best.

You might test this strategy with [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home), which writes xlsx instead of xls.  Previously it wouldn't maintain styles when editing documents, but now the style support has improved.  I have no idea about whether it retains print settings.