# How to add new column and row to .xls file using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

**How do you add a new column and/or row to a sheet in xlrd?**

I have a .xls file that I read using open_workbook() and I need to add a new column("bouncebacks") to the first sheet then new rows to that sheet but I cannot find any functions in the xlrd documentation that shows how to add new rows and/or columns?

*If I cant add a row/column in xlrd is there another way/library that allows me to add a row or column to an .xls file?*

**Can you show me how I can add a row and column to a sheet?**

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("abc.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# how do I add a new column("bouncebacks") to the sheet?
# how do I add a new row to the sheet?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xlrd is for reading from an .xls file. for writting to it use [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Comment: xlwt is for creating a new xls file.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt) out.

Answer (score 4):

`xlrd` reads `xls` files. `xlwt` creates new `xls` files. You need `xlutils`. Read [this](http://www.python-excel.org/). Work through the tutorial that you'll find mentioned there.