# Python "IndexError: list index out of range" | Goal: Read 1 excel file & append data to a 2nd excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

Goal of the script is to take the data from an excel file that is generated daily from a cron job & append that data to the bottom of a 'master' excel file.

Here is where I am right now:

```
# Find the most recent excel file created by the cron job & open it.

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())
yy = localtime.tm_year
mm = localtime.tm_mon
dd = localtime.tm_mday

file_name = 'daily_' + str(yy) + '_' + str(mm) + '_' + str(dd-1) + '.xls'
file_loc = '/Users/' + file_name
new_sheet = open_workbook(file_loc, on_demand=True).sheet_by_index(0)

# Grab all the data from the recent cron job file starting at row 2 to avoid
# including headers.

for row in range(1, new_sheet.nrows):
    values = []
    for col in range(new_sheet.ncols):
        values.append(new_sheet.cell(row,col).value)
"""
The above loop structures the list 'values[]' in a way that the print
statement of value looks like the below output; which matches the formatting of 
master_file.xlsx:

        2341511  Sports 12112 Dog   324.92
        71611    Other  18192 Cat   128.17
        ...
"""

# Find the excel master file & open it.

sheet = open_workbook('master_file.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)

# Find the first row that is empty.
new_row = sheet.nrows + 1

# Append the values[] list to the master file starting at row(new_row) and save
# the db file.

for row_num, row in enumerate(values, new_row):
    for col_num, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.row(row_num).write(col_num, col)

sheet.save('master_file.xlsx')
```

My traceback error is:

```
File "daily.py", line 45, in <module>
    sheet.row(row_num).write(col_num, col)
  File "/Users/code/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 462, in row
    for colx in xrange(len(self._cell_values[rowx]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuition from the code is that you're not actually adding a row to the worksheet prior to iterating.

xlrd doesn't look like it actually has methods to modify an existing worksheet.  Check out this SO post which might help...

[How to add new column and row to .xls file using xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763690/how-to-add-new-column-and-row-to-xls-file-using-xlrd)

Comment: I was assuming I didn't have to add a row to the worksheet because all of the writing is being handled with xlwt & the write function. Maybe I was wrong about how xlrd and xlwt play together.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I totally needed xlUtils. Yay!

Comment: Good luck!  feel free to mark as answered and/or upvote if this helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have `col(new_row)` instead of `col`, as in:

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(values, col(new_row)):
    for col_num, col(new_row) in enumerate(row):
        sheet.row(row_num).write(col_num, col(new_row))
```

?

Comment: Sorry ya I posted the wrong for loop. Edited to the correct one. Both give the Indexerror however.

Comment: @DudeAbides then it might be an off-by-1 error, did you try offsetting the indices by 1?

Comment: I tried offsetting the indices on new_row by 1 in both directions with no luck. I will keep tinkering with it I suppose.