# Change name of an excel worksheet after reading the file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am using the `xlrd` module to read an Excel file. How can I rename the first worksheet of each excel file?

Comment: not that this is terribly helpful (since i don't know any python) but the vba equivilant of what you are after is `Worksheets(1).name = "new name"`

Comment: thanx Pynner.i already tried it that way but it didn't work. thanx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can modify files with either `xlrd` or `xlwt`. You can however copy the file with `xlrd` and then modify and write the copy with `xlwt`.

Here's an example adapted from here: [writing to existing workbook using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt):

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlrd import open_workbook

# open the file you're interested
rb = open_workbook('some_document.xlsx')

# copy it to a writable variant
wb = copy(rb)

# find the index of a sheet you wanna rename,
# let's say you wanna rename Sheet1
idx = rb.sheet_names().index('Sheet1')

# now rename the sheet in the writable copy
wb.get_sheet(idx).name = u'Renamed Sheet1'

# save the new spreadsheet
wb.save('new_some_document.xlsx')

# done
```

Comment: Yeah im able to copy the file into another excel sheet but how do I CHANGE THE NAMING OF THE WORKSHEET TO INDEX OR NEW NAME. I have searched around but found nothing yet.I'm kinda new to python. thanx.

Comment: sorry about that dmytro.  thanx