# Python - iterating over, and changing, all "sheetnames" in Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am unable to Rename every Worksheet in an Excel File.
*Yes, I am aware I can do so by individual sheet*

```
import openpyxl

eventDate = ('data_entries/BOS-10.28.20.xlsx')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(eventDate)
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

> ['TC-Sheet-1', 'TC-Sheet-2', 'TC-Sheet-3', 'TC-Sheet-4', ... etc]

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    wb = sheet[9:]  # to remove the ("'TC-Sheet-" characters)
    wb.sheetnames = sheet.title
```

However, I cannot complete this loop, I am not comprehending the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file) documentation, obviously.

[An Almost Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785306/change-name-of-an-excel-worksheet-after-reading-the-file-in-python)

[This is useful for only one sheet, not an entire workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540789/how-to-rename-the-sheet-name-in-the-spread-sheet-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thank You for Any Input or Insight !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    new_name = sheet[9:] # to remove the ("'TC-Sheet-" characters)
    wb[sheet].title = new_name
```