# How to add data using python from one sheet to an existing sheet in another workbook without overwriting other sheet's data?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I have an two excel files 'file1' and 'file2'. file1 has data filled in 3 sheets. I want to copy data from file2 and append it into sheet3 in file1 and save the same file. Can anyone help me do this using python?

Answer (score 2):

xlwt is used to write into existing files.

Here is the similar thread to your question. . .

[writing to existing workbook using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can try **PyWin32** to directly run Excel.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
...
```

Some recipes [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/).

NOTE: You will need to install PyWin32 binary.