# Python: Programatically perform formula calculation of an existing spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, formula

I have a very complex spreadsheet workbook - 30 sheets, each sheet has multiple sections of tables, lots of formula and about 8MB in file size. I would like to change values of several cells in one sheet then get resulting values of cells in another sheet.

I googled to search a method to set a value of one cell and get a value of another cell. For example, let me use a super simple workbook that is only one sheet, one column and two rows.

```
Row1, Column1 (A1): 3       <--- This is a variable that will be supplied by a program.
Row2, Column1 (A2): =A1*2   <--- This is a cell from which I would like to get a calculated value with any value supplied to the A1 cell.
```

I was able to open a workbook using xlrd and get an initial value from the A2 cell. But it appears that xlrd does not have a method to let me change a cell value so I cannot change A1 value.

I followed an instruction provided by the  [writing to existing workbook using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt) link but the xlutils.copy function does not copy formulas. Therefore, when I supplied a new value to the A1 cell, the A1 cell was updated to the new value but the calculation is not done for the A2 cell.

I googled it for two days with no luck. Please help.

If there is no method in python to this, any suggestions in other tools would also be greatly appreciated. My preferred OS environment is Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be done this way? Can you do what you need using another library, say, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) and then write that out to an Excel file (which `pandas` supports)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try accessing your preferred spreadsheet tool's API and using it to manipulate cells and perform the calculations.  Since you're using Ubuntu, I'm guessing you might have LibreOffice/OpenOffice.  If so, the LibreOffice API lets you manipulate spreadsheet cells and invoke LibreOffice Calc's functionality - such as parsing the formula syntax typed into the cells and calculating the results.  The API can be accessed from Python via the PyUNO module.

Here are some links that describe using LibreOffice/OpenOffice via Python:

http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python

http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html

http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#python_examples

Comment: Solved the problem by trying the following three links... Thanks to skewart's answer. It helped me to look into PyUno. 

 - Starting, Stopping, and Connecting to OpenOffice with Python

    http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/starting-stopping-and-connecting-openoffice-python

 - Convert SpreadSheets to CSV files with Python and pyuno

    http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-spreadsheets-csv-files-python-and-pyuno-part-1v2

 - Calc Examples

    http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=56037#56037

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that your preferred environment is Ubuntu, so I apologize upfront for the fact that this is an Excel related solution but it may help you with your plight.

I'm semi-familiar with a handy excel plugin called [Data Nitro](https://datanitro.com/) - I know that it specializes in integrating python with spreadsheet formats, Excel in this case.

They have a moderate documentation and hopefully you may find that this library better supports the reading/writing of spreadsheets.

They offer some [sample python scripts](https://www.datanitro.com/quickstart.html#sample) which might give you a better idea of the suitability of Data Nitro as a solution to your problem.

Comment: I took a quick look at the Data Nitro samples. It does not use a formula embedded in an existing spreadsheet. Thanks for trying to help me though.