# How do I write to one sheet in an already existing excel sheet in Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I got an excel file that has four sheets. One sheet, sheet 4. contains data in simple CSV and the others read the data of this sheet and make different calculations and graphs. In my python application I would like to open the excel file, open sheet 4, and replace the data.  I know you technically can't open and edit excel however you like with Python, due to the complex file structure of XLS ([previous relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt)), but is there a work around for this specific case? Remember the only thing I want to do is to open the data sheet, write to it, and ignore the others...

Note: Previous answers to relevant questions have suggested using the copy function in xlutils. But that doesn't work in this case, as the rest of the sheets are rather complex. The graphs, for example, can't be preserved with the copy function.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use pyExcelerator. It did certainly a good job, but I'm not sure if it is maintained.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator/

hth.

Comment: And how exactly would you use pyExcelerator to solve the problem and work around the issues I have? Can you with pyExcelerator open a specific sheet, write to it and ignore the others? If so, how?