# AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am trying to write a string in a cell within an excel file. My code is

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
worksheet.write(0,2,"string")
```

While I was looking for a solution I leardned that it could be becouse my xlwt library has an old version. However when I checkied it I got xlwt:    0.7.5. And I was once again left clueless. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt) question might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Looking into the problem I found a solution using the `xlwt` library to write the data on a virtual workbook and the `xlutils` library to save it and thus make the virtual workbook into an actual .xls file.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
import os.path
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls',formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
wb = copy(rb) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
sheet.write(5,2,"string")
wb.save('my_workbook.xls')
```