# datemode error using xlutils

Tags: python, xlrd, xlutils

I am trying to modify Excel files using Python, but I can't get the `xlutils` package to work correctly. When I try an example (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwthttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt) thread):

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
w = copy('book1.xls')
w.get_sheet(0).write(0,0,"foo")
w.save('book2.xls')
```

I get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "names3.py", line 2, in <module>
    w = copy('names.xls')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-package
g\xlutils\copy.py", line 19, in copy
    w
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-package
g\xlutils\filter.py", line 937, in process
    reader(chain[0])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-package
g\xlutils\filter.py", line 61, in __call__
    filter.workbook(workbook,filename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-package
g\xlutils\filter.py", line 287, in workbook
    self.wtbook.dates_1904 = rdbook.datemode
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datemode'
```

I can barely find any information about this error, I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`xlutils.copy` works on a `xlrd.Book` instance. You need to create such an instance first. This works:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

wb = open_workbook('book1.xls')
wb_copy = copy(wb)
wb_copy.get_sheet(0).write(0,0,"foo")
wb_copy.save('book2.xls')
```