# Preserving Rich Text Formatting in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to add rows to an Excel file via Python (need this to run and refresh daily). The Excel file is essentially a template, at the top of which has some cells for some of the words within a cell have specific formatting, i.e. cell value "That cat is ***fluffy***".

I can't quite find a way to get Python+Excel to work together to preserve that formatting - it takes the format of the first letter in the cell and applies it across the board.

From what I can tell, this is an issue with preserving rich text, but I haven't been able to find a package that can preserve rich text, read and write excel files.

I followed this thread to come up with the code below: [writing to existing workbook using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt)

But, it looks like that copy step from the xlutils package isn't preserving the rich text formatting.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = xlrd.open_workbook(templateFile,formatting_info=True)

r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(rb) 

w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
xlsfile = Infile
insheet = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfile,formatting_info=True).sheets()[0]
outrow_idx = 10
for row_idx in xrange(insheet.nrows):
    for col_idx in xrange(insheet.ncols):
        w_sheet.write(outrow_idx, col_idx, 
                       insheet.cell_value(row_idx, col_idx))
    outrow_idx += 1

wb.save(Outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link over here, as it may help you with keeping the formatting

[Preserving styles using python's xlrd,xlwt, and xlutils.copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy)

though it doesn't keep the cell comments

Comment: I tried this earlier, but didn't have any luck. I updated my post to point out where I think the rich text attributes are falling out.

Comment: Well I have no other idea