# How do I update an existing excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, file, edit

I need to update values in an existing excel file.

I need to open an existing file.
I need to update for example the cell value in row 4 column A.
I need to close and save the existing file.

I have tried a simple code but it returns an error.

[CHECK MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVnDr.png)

EDIT: the code from the image works and executes but when i open the Excel file excel returns an error.

Comment: what does copy method does in your code ? is it copy module ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725852/writing-to-existing-workbook-using-xlwt may be useful. My own experiences were with .xls files so that may not be helpful - when working with those it was only possible if your input file was simple enough, because some formatting information got lost between opening the input file and creating a writeable version. But the .xslx format is different enough that that may not hold.

Comment: I don't know actually. I followed a tutorial which included it.

Answer (score 1):

> workable_copy = copy(read_excel)
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

This message means that you're calling a module as though it were a function. Since your script recognizes [`copy`](https://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html) as a module, I assume you've imported it with `import xlutils.copy`. However, if you want to use the function without qualifying it, you have to import it like this:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
```

Comment: Just guessing, but this is _probably_ meant to be the xsutils.copy `copy` method - https://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Oh yeah, that is a better guess.

Comment: I got the code to compile and execute but when I open the resulting excel file, excel returns an error