# how to append particular excel cell value using python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, xlutils

cell (1,1) should have "Put me in same cell":

```
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1')
sheet.write(1, 1, "Put me")
n=10
if n>0: 
    sheet.write(1, 1, "in same cell")
```

Comment: What library is that? What does it write instead of the expected result?

Comment: library is xlwt nd it just give overwrite error.

Comment: Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'sheet1' rowx=1 colx=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the default xlwt behavior, you can either override that with

```
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679641/770830))
That will only overwrite the original value `Put me`, though.

You'll have to merge the values manually, like this:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1')
buf = StringIO()
buf.write('Put me')
if some_condition:
   buf.write(' in same cell')

sheet.write(1, 1, buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add these two values with different formating. Like 'Put me' (in blue colour) and 'in same cell' (in red colour)

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: i hv edited my comment above. did you got it or should i explain my question more?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know how to deal with colors in xlwt.

Comment: @Rahul Did you get any answers for your color related query in xlwt?

Answer (score 0):

try openpyxl, this works for me:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


def append_to_cell(location,text,sheet):
    new = sheet.cell(location).value+text
    sheet.cell(location).value=new

    return 

file_name='example.xlsx'
cell='A1'
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = 'test Sheet'
ws.cell(cell).value = 'write this '
append_to_cell(cell,'in same cell',ws)
wb.save(filename=file_name)
```